# How to copy icon from font in i3wm i3block setup

Tags: i3-window-manager

i am setting up a i3block in i3wm. Now i have font-awesome installed in proper directory.

I am puzzled with one thing how icon is copied to the below command. When i google i already see the shell script which is having icon placed. But how they are getting this icon from font.

```
[public-ip]
command=echo "Public IP: "$(wget -qO - icanhazip.com)
interval=once
```

Let us take an example, Instead of the text "Public Ip". I want an icon. But how do i copy it from my font? What tool i should use?

If i use https://bluejamesbond.github.io/CharacterMap/ I am not finding any copy option.

Answer (score 0):

Just copy the icon. It easy as it sounds. 
Go to https://fontawesome.com/cheatsheet, find your desired icon and copy icon, not name neither code, just icon and paste it instead of text 'Public IP'. Restart i3 and it works.